# ActivityNotFoundException when opening a URL in browser on notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to open a URL on notification click. There are 2 browsers installed including Chrome but the code doesn't work.

I'm using this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieURL));
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(browserIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, browserIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle(movieName + " is available")
                        .setContentText("Click here to open in browser")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Error:
`No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=link>https: flg=0x10008000 }`

Android version is 6 and I'm running this in AsyncTask in as a service, if that's relevant. There's nothing wrong with the URL. I got data from it before and 'https://' part is not missing from it.

I'm new to android so I'm hoping for a simplified explanation :)

Comment: I suppose the problem is in a wrong url

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin No, I printed the url to the log to check. It's "https://yts.lt/movie/furie-2019". So there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: just try add scheme to your url `https://yts.lt`. There is no scheme at your url, so, I assume its a real problem

Comment: just curious. do you even have a browser installed on your phone

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin What's a scheme and how do I do that? Sorry, I'm new to Android

Comment: He means a protocol. And you posted the url in a wrong way. Nobody can see that it has protocol `https://` at the start. Dont use quotes but ticks. (well the right ticks, there are several).

Comment: @Mercato Yeah, there are two, as I stated in the beginning of the question

Comment: `dat=link>https:` -- your URL appears to be invalid. If you try pasting `link>https:` in your Web browser's address bar, you will not get a Web page. "I printed the url to the log to check" -- the `Intent` does not seem to have that URL. It has `link>https:`.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the protocol. It looks like your url is invalid. Try `https://yts.lt/movie/furie-2019`. It should work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah right. I hadn't seen a url in the log before. I thought it was pointing at the link or something. Got it, Thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: You seem to forget that Alexander told you in the first comment that your url was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieURL));
```

I am uncertain what `movieURL` contains, but it is turning into `link>https:` when you parse it. That is not a valid URL, and Android will not find an app to be able to handle `ACTION_VIEW` for it.

Note that raising a `Notification` from your app, where the `Notification` launches a third-party app when clicked, is unusual. The typical point behind a `Notification` is to allow the user to control aspects of your app's behavior. If your objective is to launch an activity from your own app, do not use an implicit `Intent` (`new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ...)`). Instead, use an explicit `Intent` (`new Intent(this, YourAwesomeActivity.class)`). You can still use `setAction()` or `putExtra()` to attach information to tell your activity what to display.

Comment: This is outside the question but, it opens the browser *at the same time* the notification is displayed. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @TashilaPathum: Make sure that you are not calling `startActivity()` with that `Intent` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it first and see what is the result

```
if (browserIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: It just hides the real problem, but not solving it. The original problem is about why there is no activity to resolve simple view URL intent, but your solution just check does it possible to resolve an intent.

Comment: @mona it will not work in android 13